# antonym for "compressive"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

The tidal field (of the Earth on the Moon, for example) is compressive in the two tangential directions, but *stretching* in the radial direction. I.e. it pulls at the Moon (towards Earth and in the opposite direction).

What is more appropriate/suitable than *stretching* here?

EDIT: an antonym for "compression" is "expansion", but is "expansive" appropriate?

Comment: Can you describe what should go in place of "_???_" in words, as I'm not really sure what concept you want to express. _An_ opposite of _compressive_ could be _expansive_; and in [longitudinal waves](https://www.siyavula.com/read/science/grade-10/longitudinal-waves/09-longitudinal-waves-02) you have _compression_ and _rarefaction_. But I'm not certain either apply to "tidal fields".

Comment: sounds like a physics site ?

Comment: @lbf, well it's obviously physics related, but it's the English that I'm struggling with.

Comment: @TripeHound *rarefaction* is not exactly an antonym for compression, though in the context of waves, it's antonym for some *effect* of compression.

Comment: Then [_tensive_](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tensive) is probably the correct term, but from your comments below, I'm not sure if it's what you want. And you seem to have changed in those comments from wanting an antonym to _compressive_ to one of the _process of compression_

Answer (score 1):

Consider calling it *tensile*.

> **tensile** *adjective*
>   1 Relating to tension.
>   ‘Compressive forces are generally significantly greater than the tensile forces generated in a tensile test.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tensile)

Your sample sentence would then look like this:

- The tidal field (of the Earth on the Moon, for example) is **compressive** in the two tangential directions, but **tensile** in the radial direction.

The related word *tension* is an antonym to *compression*.

> **tension** *noun*
>   1 The state of being stretched tight.
>   ‘the parachute keeps the cable under tension as it drops’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tension)

Here's an example of these two words used as antonyms (terms highlighted here in bold):

> The relation between basic and drying creep in **tension** compared to basic and drying creep in **compression** was investigated.
>   - [Comparison of concrete creep in tension and in compression](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0008884613000768) by Pierre Rossi, Jean-Louis Tailhan and Fabrice Le Maou

Comment: This is not correct: tension is not an antonym to compression: it describes the **state** of being stretched, while compression describes a **process**.

Comment: @Walter Perhaps the gerund *tensioning* would be a closer match.

Comment: Hmmm. "tensioning" is IMHO worse than "stretching" (because less known).

Comment: @Walter Compare “the improper compression of the unit led to problems” with “the improper tensioning of the wires caused them to snap”. Antonyms are notorious for fitting well in one context and badly in others.

Comment: @Walter I've added an example to show *tension* used as a direct antonym to *compression* in a published work.

Answer (score 1):

**Dilation**. Real-world example from [Mid-Ocean Ridges: Dynamics of Processes Associated with the Creation of New Oceanic Crust](https://books.google.com/books?id=q63nttvFDUQC&pg=PA202&lpg=PA202&dq=%22tidal+dilation%22&source=bl&ots=CYKeKy8Svr&sig=RdfCzeiOCQpQPzUYT-y_25OprU8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhysWPhsjaAhUCElAKHd6WAOUQ6AEILjAA#v=onepage&q=%22tidal%20dilation%22&f=false) (emphasis is mine):

> The **tidal dilation** of continental aquifers also acts to displace the water level within the aquifer.

According to [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dilate), dilate is:

> Make or become wider, larger, or more open.

Attribution:

[1](https://books.google.com/books?id=q63nttvFDUQC&pg=PA202&lpg=PA202&dq=%22tidal+dilation%22&source=bl&ots=CYKeKy8Svr&sig=RdfCzeiOCQpQPzUYT-y_25OprU8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhysWPhsjaAhUCElAKHd6WAOUQ6AEILjAA#v=onepage&q=%22tidal%20dilation%22&f=false) Cann, J.R., Cann, J.R., Elderfield, H., Elderfield, H. & Laughton, A.S. (1999). Mid-Ocean Ridges: Dynamics of Processes Associated with the Creation of New Oceanic Crust. Cambridge University Press

[2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dilate) "Dilate | Definition of Dilate in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed April 20, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dilate.

Answer (score 0):

> is "expansive" appropriate

Yes, from M-W: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expansive

> **EXPANSIVE**
>
> 2. causing or tending to cause expansion